# No PDFJS.workerSrc specified

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Trying to use PDF JS in a local Apache server and receiving the following error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified
```

This is very weird, because I'm following all that the examples specifies here http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/.

I have, in my main folder, a sample file called `file.pdf` and I'm just trying to display it. I did it by using a iframe with a `file` parameter:

```
<iframe src="./web/viewer.html?file=http://localhost:99/PDF/arquivo.pdf" width="1800px" height="900px" />
```

And now I'm trying to use the JavaScript API to display it. I'm trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./build/pdf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            PDFJS.getDocument('arquivo.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
                // Here I use it
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I try to include `pdf.worker.js` manually, I receive:

```
GET http://localhost:99/PDF/build/pdf.worker.worker.js 404 (Not Found)
```

because it programmatically includes **pdf.worker.js**.

With the sample code I posted here, I receive a log and an error:

```
Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified pdf.js:249
    at error (http://localhost:99/PDF/build/pdf.js:251:15)
    at Object.WorkerTransport (http://localhost:99/PDF/build/pdf.js:2305:9)
    at Object.getDocument (http://localhost:99/PDF/build/pdf.js:1805:15)
    at http://localhost:99/PDF/:6:10 pdf.js:251
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown" pdf.js:234
Uncaught Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified
```

Do I need to manually specify **pdf.worker.js**?
Please, what can I try to solve this?

Thank you so much!

(*) - I can see a lack of good content and a well explained documentation of PDF.JS.

Comment: does this help https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/helloworld.html or https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L73 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a similar error and I fixed it by specifying the pdf.worker.js explicitly at the end of the pdf.js

```
if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  // workerSrc is not set -- using last script url to define default location
  ****** I have no clue what the code below hope to accomplish ********
  ****** How can it locate the script container by assuming it ********
  ****** always would be at the end of <body> or <head> ????   ********
  PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var scriptTagContainer = document.body ||
                             document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var pdfjsSrc = scriptTagContainer.lastChild.src;
    return pdfjsSrc && pdfjsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
  })();


  ****** Here I just hardcode the location of the needed file *********
  ****** This is the part that makes it work.                 *********
  ****** Obviously, tailor this to the same path of pdf.js    *********
  PDFJS.workerSrc = '/static/js/pdf.worker.js';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do PDFJS.workerSrc = "/someplace/pdf.worker.js"; before PDFJS.getDocument, so you wouldn't need to modify pdf.js files?

Comment: That may also work. If you test it and it works, come back here and share it with everyone.

Comment: Hi Will, the code you've fixed has already been solved. Download compatibility.js and reference it on your page to solve this issue. IE11 used to work for me without compatibility.js before I upgraded from build 1.0.1040 to 1.3.91. Maybe not a good idea to add workarounds as the problem has been already solved by the PDFJS maintainers.

Comment: I put in this answer before there is a compatibility.js. If the compatibility.js fix the problem, then yes, no need to do this work around. But what am I supposed to do with this answer? Delete it?

Answer (score 11):

Include compatibility.js to fix the "Uncaught Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified" error on IE11.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/shared/compatibility.js

```
<script src="compatibility.js"></script>
<script src="pdf.js"></script>
```

compatibility.js implements any missing functionality required by PDFJS.

**Note:** It should be loaded *before* PDFJS, not after.

Comment: Well, in 2014, when I asked the question, we didn't yet have `compatibility.js`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: IE11 does not understands `require()`.

Answer (score 8):

Specify psd.worker.js file path in your page where you want to use the pdf.js file (viewer.html in case you are using viewer.html come with distribution bundle) like this. It work for me.

```
<script>
    PDFJS.workerSrc ='path to psd.worker.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I added below code in end of pdf.js and working fine

```
if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var scriptTagContainer = document.body ||
                             document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var pdfjsSrc = scriptTagContainer.lastChild.src;
    return pdfjsSrc && pdfjsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
  })();
  PDFJS.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to pdf.js

search function getWorkerSrc()

replace this lines

```
pdfjsFilePath = "YOUR_PATH_TO_JS_FILE/pdf.worker.js";
if (pdfjsFilePath) {
  return pdfjsFilePath;
}
```

Comment: just set PDFJS.workerSrc = "YOUR_PATH_TO_JS_FILE/pdf.worker.js";

Comment: Never manually edit library files. Unless you're pushing up a pull request. ;}