# Reading a PDF file with Node / NWJS App

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, nodes, nwjs

First of all thanks for looking into this. I'm building a simple nwjs app and having a hard time with reading a PDF file.

I've tried several libraries (pdf2json, pdfreader, pdf2text) and all of them returned the following error.

```
Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified
at error (eval at <anonymous> (/node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:1), <anonymous>:195:9)
at new WorkerTransport (eval at <anonymous> (/node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:1), <anonymous>:42944:9)
at Object.getDocument (eval at <anonymous> (/node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:1), <anonymous>:42547:15)
.....
```

Seems like all of those libraries are based on pdf.js and the problem is coming from there.

I strip down my js to bare bone to isolate the issue.

```
var reader = require('pdfreader');

new reader.PdfReader().parseFileItems("/path/to/file.pdf", function(err, item){
    console.log(err, item);
});
```

This works if I run it as a regular node script `node myfile.js` but it does not work when i run it as a nwjs app.

I wasn't able to find any other reliable native js library either.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the compatbilty script mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101071/no-pdfjs-workersrc-specified

Comment: @Chathura86, It's been a long time you have asked this question. Just wanted to know if you got some solution for this problem? I'm also stuck at the exact same step with same issue. Any help would be appreciated.