# Electron convert PDF to Text

Tags: pdf, electron

I'm developing an electron app. The application should receive a PDF file and transform into txt. I used the lib `PDF2JSON` however, if used along with the electron, it gives the following worker error:

```
Uncaught Error: No PDFJS.workerSrc specified
```

What would be the best way to convert PDF to text using Electron without having to redirect to an external server?

```
  const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
    const fs = require('fs');
    const PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

    const pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);



    document.getElementById('select-file').addEventListener('click',function(){
        dialog.showOpenDialog(function (fileNames) {
            if(fileNames === undefined){
                console.log("No file selected");
            }else{
                const file = fileNames[0];

                pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
                pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
                    fs.writeFile("content.txt", pdfParser.getRawTextContent());
                });

                pdfParser.loadPDF(file);

            }
        });
    },false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No PDFJS.workerSrc specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101071/no-pdfjs-workersrc-specified)

Comment: didnt work this methods

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit of code you did use within your app?

Comment: PDF2JSON continued to cause me issues However, I was able to successfully use pdf-parse to extract text in an Electron app (using the ipc calls per Carlos Oropesa's answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing an electron app and I have the same issue (try to read a PDF and 'No PDFJS.workerSrc specified' ), finally I got it. I did the same idea than @slowjack2k (but without coffeescript hehe).

First, install [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json).

Then, in the main.js

```
const { ipcMain } = require( 'electron' );
const PDFParser = require( 'pdf2json' );

ipcMain.on( 'prefix-convert-pdf', ( event, file_base_path ) => {
    new PDFParser()
        .on( "pdfParser_dataError", errData => {
            event.sender.send( 'prefix-pdf-converted-error', errData );
        })
        .on( "pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
            event.sender.send( 'prefix-pdf-converted', pdfData );
        })
        .loadPDF( file_base_path );
});
```

And in the renderer.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require( 'electron' );

document.getElementById( 'the-button' ).addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send( 'prefix-convert-pdf', 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\my-pdf.pdf' );
    // Better use require('path'), this is a simple way to understand how it works.
});

ipcRenderer
    .on( 'prefix-pdf-converted-error', ( event, errData ) => {
        console.error( errData );
        //do whatever you want in the DOM
    })
    .on( 'prefix-pdf-converted', ( event, pdfData ) => {
        console.log( pdfData );
        //do whatever you want in the DOM
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You'r code looks like you'r doing all the pdf2json work within your renderer procress. Within the renderer process you don't have the full feature set of nodejs available.

pdf2json is until now not designed to run within a browser. You can get it to work by putting all the pdf2json related stuff into your renderer process like this:

Within your renderer Process (coffee script):

```
{app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
PDFParser = require("pdf2json")

ipcMain.on 'convert-pdf', (event, path_to_file) ->
  console.log "Converting pdf " + path_to_file
  pdfParser = new PDFParser()

  pdfParser.on "pdfParser_dataError", (errData) ->
    console.error(errData.parserError)

  pdfParser.on "pdfParser_dataReady", (pdfData) =>
    console.log "sending data to renderer process"
    console.log JSON.stringify(pdfData)
    event.sender.send 'pdf-converted',  pdfData

    pdfParser.loadPDF(path_to_file)
```

Within your renderer:

```
<a href="#" id="convert-pdf"> doit </a> <span id="pdf-data">0</span>
  <script>
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
    let link = document.querySelector('#convert-pdf');
    link.addEventListener("click",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ipcRenderer.send('convert-pdf', '/the/file.pdf');
    },
    false);

    ipcRenderer.on('pdf-converted', (event, data) => {
      let span =  document.querySelector('#pdf-data');
      span.textContent=JSON.stringify(data);
    });
 </script>
```

Your also using `remote` to show a dialog (dialog is part of the main process). remote is only a shortcut for using all the messaging in a synchronous way. You can achieve the same with `ipcRenderer.sendSync` and seperate more clearly renderer actions from main actions.

Comment: `Within the renderer process you don't have the full feature set of nodejs available`, this is just not true. In the renderers you have access to ALL nodejs features

Comment: Take a look at `setIntervall`. Within the renderer process the browser implementation is used and not the nodejs version. Both version differ within their return value. As far as I know the chrome version of a function wins over the nodejs version most of the time. Furthermore you can switch off node integration completely during the creation  of a browserwindow instance. So in my point of view you have a lot of nodejs features available, but not a full set.

Comment: You can access the node version like: `const timers = require('timers'); timers.setInterval(() => { }, 1000)`. Sure there are differences but it's misleading to say `you don't have the full feature set of nodejs available`.

Comment: This differences are undocumented. You can't just use every npm module within your renderer process  like you can use it within your main process (for instance batch-cluster) because of such differences. So in my point of view as long as you can't use every npm module within your renderer process you don't have the full feature set of nodejs available within your renderer. You may say you have most features available, but as long as one feature is missing you don't have the full feature set available and it can happen that your loved module want work within the renderer.

Comment: `batch-cluster` is the first npm module I've come across which has this issue. We're using dozens of npm modules including native ones in the renderer in production apps without issue. I'm not debating whether there are differences, there clearly are. Rather than say `you don't have the full feature set of nodejs available` which is factually incorrect, say that there are some differences which may stop some modules from working. Just doing everything in the main process is not the answer, Electron was not designed to be used like that.